# Is there an away3D hitTestObject equivalent?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

i am working with away3D and i find myself in dire need of a hitTestObject-method. 
As far as i have found out, there is no such method present in the library. I have already tried distanceTo, but that calculates the distance from the centerPoints, so using this method is not an option since i need to detect all collisions.

Does anyone have a good way of detecting hits on another object in away3D? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Away3D is a renderer, not a physics engine.  To have 'collisions', you would need some kind of physics engine involved like [JigLib](http://www.jiglibflash.com/blog/).

Comment: Should mark his answer as correct, as it is. You can use the object's 3D transformation matrix to compare it manually against other objects matrices to see if one body collides with another but this would be a manually coded solution, not a prebuilt engine solution. There are physics libraries available for the away3d 4.0 (flash player 11) build, the best is an alchemy port of the C++ bullet physics library here: http://code.google.com/p/bulletflash/

Comment: Well, I am trying it out right now and it's working pretty good :)